# implement HttpServiceFactory for my own type in Rust

Tags: rust, actix-web

I started to implement a http backend with rust based on actix-web. For that I defined my own type "HttpPayload" which should be able to expose its internal data through http.

Following is a minimal code snipped showing my use case:

```
use actix_cors::Cors;
use actix_web::{ web, App, HttpServer, HttpResponse, Responder, dev::HttpServiceFactory };

pub async fn not_found() -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::NotFound()
      .content_type("text/html; charset=utf-8")
      .body("<html><head><title>Not Found</title></head><body><h1>Not Found!</h1></body></html>")
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct HttpPayload {
    path: String,
    data: String,
}

impl HttpPayload {
    pub fn new(path: String, data: String) -> Self {
        HttpPayload { path: path, data: data }
    }

    async fn request_data(&self) -> HttpResponse {
        HttpResponse::Ok()
            .content_type("text/plain")
            .body(self.data.clone())
    }
}

impl HttpServiceFactory for HttpPayload {
    fn register(self, config: &mut actix_web::dev::AppService) {
        web::resource(self.path).to(|| { self.request_data() } ).register(config); // <-- here is the issue
    }
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let httpHandlerA: HttpPayload = HttpPayload::new("DemoA".to_string(), "DataA".to_string());
    let httpHandlerB: HttpPayload = HttpPayload::new("DemoB".to_string(), "DataB".to_string());

    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
          .wrap(Cors::default().allow_any_origin())
          .service(httpHandlerA.clone())
          .service(httpHandlerB.clone())
          .default_service(web::to(not_found))
    })
    .bind(("0.0.0.0", 4242))?.run().await
}
```

When using this code, I get the compilation error in the `register` method: `may outlive borrowed value 'self'`. The compiler hint, to use move result in additional errors.

What am I doing wrong? And how could a *implementation* register it self on a `HttpServer`?

**Edit:**
Add the whole compiler output:

```
cargo build
   Compiling rustDataExchange v0.1.0 (C:\Projects\rustDataExchange)
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `self`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src\main.rs:78:37
   |
78 |         web::resource(self.path).to(|| { self.request_data() } ).register(config); // <-- here is the issue
   |                                     ^^   ---- `self` is borrowed here
   |                                     |
   |                                     may outlive borrowed value `self`
   |
note: function requires argument type to outlive `'static`
  --> src\main.rs:78:9
   |
78 |         web::resource(self.path).to(|| { self.request_data() } ).register(config); // <-- here is the issue
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `self` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
78 |         web::resource(self.path).to(move || { self.request_data() } ).register(config); // <-- here is the issue
   |                                     ++++

error[E0382]: borrow of partially moved value: `self`
  --> src\main.rs:78:37
   |
78 |         web::resource(self.path).to(|| { self.request_data() } ).register(config); // <-- here is the issue
   |                       ---------     ^^   ---- borrow occurs due to use in closure
   |                       |             |
   |                       |             value borrowed here after partial move
   |                       value partially moved here
   |
   = note: partial move occurs because `self.path` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0373, E0382.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0373`.
error: could not compile `rustDataExchange` (bin "rustDataExchange") due to 2 previous errors
```

**Edit2:**

use `web::resource(self.path.clone()).to(move || { self.request_data() } ).register(config); // <-- here is the issue` which returns the compiler error:

```
cargo build
   Compiling rustDataExchange v0.1.0 (C:\Projects\git\hackingHours\technology-matching-sm\rustDataExchange)
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src\main.rs:78:55
   |
78 |         web::resource(self.path.clone()).to(move || { self.request_data() } ).register(config); // <-- here is the issue
   |                                             -------   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
   |                                             |     |
   |                                             |     return type of closure `impl std::future::Future<Output = HttpResponse>` contains a lifetime `'2`
   |                                             lifetime `'1` represents this closure's body
   |
   = note: closure implements `Fn`, so references to captured variables can't escape the closure

error: could not compile `rustDataExchange` (bin "rustDataExchange") due to previous error
```

Does anyone has an idea, how to use self in the closure the right way?

Additionally, maybe a solution without `move` is a better one, because than more than one resources could be registered...?

Comment: Please add the complete error message from the compiler (i.e. `cargo build`) not your IDE or a vague excerpt.

Comment: My guess is that you'll have to clone `self.path` and `move` `self` into the closure, but without the proper compiler errors it's hard to tell.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I just added the whole error message and also tried to use the  `move` ...

Answer (score 0):

i don't know much about rust-lang, but i think your code should be looks like this:

```rust
use actix_cors::Cors;
use actix_web::{web, App, HttpServer, HttpResponse, Responder, dev::HttpServiceFactory};

pub async fn not_found() -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::NotFound()
        .content_type("text/html; charset=utf-8")
        .body("<html><head><title>Not Found</title></head><body><h1>Not Found!</h1></body></html>")
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct HttpPayload {
    path: String,
    _data: String,
}

impl HttpPayload {
    pub fn new(path: String, data: String) -> Self {
        HttpPayload { path, _data: data }
    }
}

impl HttpServiceFactory for HttpPayload {
    fn register(self, config: &mut actix_web::dev::AppService) {
        let path = self.path;

        let request_data = move || {
            async move {
                HttpResponse::Ok().content_type("text/plain").body("")
            }
        };

        web::resource(path).to(request_data).register(config);
    }
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let http_handler_a: HttpPayload = HttpPayload::new("DemoA".to_string(), "DataA".to_string());
    let http_handler_b: HttpPayload = HttpPayload::new("DemoB".to_string(), "DataB".to_string());

    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .wrap(Cors::default().allow_any_origin())
            .service(http_handler_a.clone())
            .service(http_handler_b.clone())
            .default_service(web::to(not_found))
    })
        .bind(("0.0.0.0", 4242))?.run().await
}
```

and i think you can't use `self.*` as body for `HttpResponse`

if i understand correctly what you want, i can suggest to put it in the config (in `static`) and use the values from the config, but it is hardly the best practice

edit:
or you can use this:

```rust
use std::future::Future;
use actix_cors::Cors;
use actix_web::{web, App, HttpServer, HttpResponse, Responder, dev::HttpServiceFactory};

pub async fn not_found() -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::NotFound()
        .content_type("text/html; charset=utf-8")
        .body("<html><head><title>Not Found</title></head><body><h1>Not Found!</h1></body></html>")
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct HttpPayload {
    path: String,
    data: String,
}

impl HttpPayload {
    pub fn new(path: String, data: String) -> Self {
        HttpPayload { path, data }
    }
}

impl HttpServiceFactory for HttpPayload {
    fn register(self, config: &mut actix_web::dev::AppService) {
        let path = self.path;

        web::resource(path).to(move || request_data(self.data.clone())).register(config);
    }
}

#[allow(clippy::manual_async_fn)]
fn request_data(data: String) -> impl Future<Output=HttpResponse> + Sized {
    async move {
        HttpResponse::Ok().content_type("text/plain").body(data)
    }
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let http_handler_a: HttpPayload = HttpPayload::new("DemoA".to_string(), "DataA".to_string());
    let http_handler_b: HttpPayload = HttpPayload::new("DemoB".to_string(), "DataB".to_string());

    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .wrap(Cors::default().allow_any_origin())
            .service(http_handler_a.clone())
            .service(http_handler_b.clone())
            .default_service(web::to(not_found))
    })
        .bind(("0.0.0.0", 4242))?.run().await
}
```